# Route::resource issue when its under a group-route with a prefix

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

When I use a route::resource under a group-route that has a prefix applied, I get a "RouteNotFoundException"

For example I have this

```
/// ROUTES FILE
    $languages = array('gr','en');
    $locale = \Request::segment(1);
    if(in_array($locale, $languages)){
    \App::setLocale($locale);
    }else{
    $locale = null;
    App::setLocale("gr");
    }
    Route::group(array('before'=>'auth','domain' => 'app.domain.dev','prefix'=>"$locale"), function(){
    Route::resource('invoices', '\ctrl\app\InvoicesController');
    });
```

I get this error

> Symfony \ Component \ Routing \ Exception \ RouteNotFoundException
>   Unable to generate a URL for the named route "invoices.index" as such
>   route does not exist.

Comment: Do you already have InvoicesControlle? Does the InvoicesController have 'getIndex()`?

Comment: Its index() not getIndex() and it works ok if I don't use the prefix.

Comment: Ah my bad, I thought it was a `Route::controller()`